# Preventing MFMailComposeViewController from scaling animated GIFs

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, animated-gif

I'm attaching an animated GIF to an email to be sent with MFMailComposeViewController.  If the GIF is of sufficient size the MFMailComposeViewController will ask the user whether they want to resize it to a smaller size.  Unfortunately, the animation will not be preserved in the resized image.

How do I either forbid MFMailComposeViewController to resize the image or make it preserve the animation?

Answer (score 3):

There’s no built-in API to do this, but one option is to compress the animated GIF into a ZIP, then attach that. The MFMailComposeViewController won’t offer to resize the ZIP (unless it’s peeking into its contents).