# iOS: When does mail ask to reduce message size by scaling image when a large image is attached?

Tags: ios, image, email, gif

In my iOS app, I need the user to be able to send email with a GIF image attachment. I implemented this by using MFMailComposeViewController. If the file size of the GIF image is small, everything works OK. However, if the image size is large, iOS asks to reduce the image size. If the user accepts to reduce image size, the animation of GIF is gone. Actually, this is the same problem as asked here: [Preventing MFMailComposeViewController from scaling animated GIFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522948/preventing-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-from-scaling-animated-gifs?rq=1)

My understanding is that there is no way to avoid iOS to ask to reduce size. Therefore, the solution I am thinking is as follows: I will pre-compress and generate a new gif with reduced file size before attaching so that it will always be small enough.

So my question is: Is there an image file size that is guarantee to not result in iOS's asking to reduce image size? For example, is there something like "the mail will never ask to reduce image size if the attached image file is less than X KB" and what is X?

Comment: I don't believe this is documented anywhere. You will have to use trial and error to discover the threshold. Keep in mind that the threshold could be different in different versions of iOS. Then again, the reduction is most likely due to limits on email attachment size and that probably hasn't changed with versions of iOS.

Comment: I've scoured the `MFMailComposeViewController` class reference as well as the sample code they provide and cannot find it documented anywhere.  Anyone know of a site/application I can generate image files of a specific file size?  I will use trail and error as @rmaddy has suggested.  I believe the threshold is somewhere around 1-2MB.  I've asked a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996209/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-force-actual-size-on-image-attachment

Comment: I'm scaling down my JPG images to 1024x768 or 768x1024 and most of the time this is sufficient to prevent Apple from asking if I want to further scale my image down.   But, I have seen that when the image I take has a lot of fine detail in it, even cutting it down as I do does not prevent the query.   I'm looking at one right now where the message says my message is 510KB and it is triggering the question.   I'm wondering if 500KB is the limit.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer to the threshold question and a method to reduce an image down and reliably avoid Apple querying if you want to scale the image size down.

Some background:

In my App, I give the user the option of automatically scaling their image down to 1024x768 before E-Mailing it as a way of avoiding Apple's 'do you want to scale your image down?' query.

For a long time, I thought that this amount of descaling was sufficient.  But I've discovered that if their image has enough fine detail in it, then even at 1024x768, it can still trigger Apple's query.

So, the code below is how I deal with this problem.   Note that if the getMinImgSizFlag is TRUE, I've already descaled the image to 1024x768 elsewhere.automatically

```
//...convert the UIImage into NSData, as the email controller requires, using
//   a default JPG compression value of 90%.

float jpgCompression = 0.9f;

imageAsNSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( [self camImage], jpgCompression );

if ( [gDB getMinImgSizFlag] == TRUE )
    {
    //...if we are here, the user has opted to pre emptively scale their
    //   image down to 1024x768 to avoid Apple's 'scale the image down?'
    //   query.
    //
    //   if so, then we will do a bit more testing because even with
    //   the image scaled down, if it has a lot of fine detail, it may
    //   still exceed a critical size threashold and trigger the query.
    //
    //   it's been empirically determined that the critical size threashold
    //   falls between 391K and 394K bytes.
    //
    //   if we determine that the compressed image, at the default JPG
    //   compression, is still larger than the critical size threashold,
    //   then we will begin looping and increasing the JPG compression
    //   until the image size drops below 380K.
    //
    //   the aproximately 10K between our limit, 380K, and Apple's
    //   critical size threashold allows for the possibility that Apple
    //   may be including the contribution of the E-Mail's text size into
    //   its threashold calculations.

    while ( [imageAsNSData length] > 380000 )
       {
       jpgCompression -= 0.05f;
       imageAsNSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( [self camImage], jpgCompression );
       }
    }
```

That's it.  I've tested this code and it reliably allows me to avoid Apple's do you want to scale your image down before emailing it query.